# Passing by pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I am confused between these two functions:

```
void Swap_byPointer1(int *x, int *y){
    int *temp=new int;
    temp=x;
    x=y;
    y=temp;
}
```

---

```
void Swap_byPointer2(int *x, int *y){
    int *temp=new int;
    *temp=*x;
    *x=*y;
    *y=*temp;
}
```

Why `Swap_byPointer2` succeeds to swap between x and y, and `Swap_byPointer1`does not?

Comment: +1 for a well-formatted question.

Comment: version 1 is a noop and a memory leak. version 2 is only a memory leak.

Comment: The memory leak is caused by the unnecessary `new int`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first snippet swaps the memory addresses which are the values of the pointers. Since the pointers are local copies, this has no effect for the caller.

Rewritten without a memory leak:

```
void Swap_byPointer1(int *x, int *y){
    //e.g x = 0xDEADBEEF and y = 0xCAFEBABE;
    int *temp=x;
    x=y;
    y=temp;
    //now x = 0xCAFEBABE and y = 0xDEADBEEF
}
```

The second swaps the pointees (objects that the pointers point to).

Rewritten without a memory leak:

```
void Swap_byPointer2(int *x, int *y){
    //e.g *x = 100 and *y = 200
    int temp =*x;
    *x=*y;
    *y=temp;
    //now *x = 200 and *y = 100
    //there are now different values at the original memory locations
}
```

(Pointers can point to dynamically allocated objects, but don't have to. Using a pointer does not mean there has to be a **new**-allocation. Pointers can point to objects with automatic lifetime as well.)

Comment: One note, because it may not be obvious to the OP. `x` and `y` are local to the functions, any changes on `x` and `y` are purely contained within the function and do not affect the outer world. This is what happens in the first function. On the other hand, the second function changes what `x` and `y` *point to*, which does affect the outer world.

Answer (score 7):

In your first function you're swapping the pointers themselves, and in the second you're swapping the values of what the pointers point to, ie pointers dereferenced.

If you want to change what a pointer points to, you should pass a pointer to a pointer (ie `int**x`) and change the second pointer.

Like so

```
void Swap_byPointer1(int **x, int **y){
    int *temp;
    temp=*x;
    *x=*y;
    *y=*temp;
}
```

Comment: Also, both have a memory leak

Comment: you don't swap what the pointers point to, you only swap the local copies, the original passed pointers are unchanged.

Comment: If you swap what they point to then after swap they would point to the other pointer's previous location, meaning it should still work.

Comment: @UncleBens Yes, mistake in my answer

Comment: In both examples, there is no need for `new int`.  Just declare the integer or the pointer to integer.  C++ is not like Java nor C# in this respect.

Comment: @sim642, swapping the pointers and swapping the values are not equivalent. Suppose they point to characters in a string or other structure, or to memory-mapped IO registers?

Answer (score 7):

Initial setup of the functions, (common for both) (mock values)

(Assumption : *The values written outside the boxes are address.*)

[image]

Function swap_byPointer1,

[image]

Function swapby_Pointer2,

[image]

Hope this helped to get a picture of whats happening, Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

Because the parameters are passed by value. In the first code sample all you do is swap local copies of the pointers. The second example actually writes to the pointees.

Better still would be to use pass by reference and avoid heap allocation by using a stack allocated temp int.

```
void SwapByRef(int &x, int &y)
{
    int temp=x;     
    x=y;     
    y=temp;
}
....
int x=1;
int y=2;
SwapByRef(x, y);
```

As others have pointed out, both of your code samples leak memory because temp is never deleted. For a simple int like this, just use a stack allocated local int variable for your temp.

Answer (score 4):

The first function is just reassigning the local copy of pointers, not modifying the underlying values.  When it returns, it will have had no effect (other than allocating a new int)